# Substitute the value of a Make variables with multiple alterations?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
#
# Sources are .c and .s files
#
# Append .o to both .c and .s:  
PRJ_OBJ := $(addprefix $(BUILD_PATH)/,$(addsuffix .o, $(PRJ_SRC)))
# Create .c.d from .c.o and .s.d from s.o:
PRJ_DEP_TEMP := $(PRJ_OBJ:.c.o=.c.d)
PRJ_DEP += $(PRJ_DEP_TEMP:.s.o=.s.d)
```

How could I do both replacements `.c.o=.c.d` and `.s.o=.s.d` in one line instead of two?

Doc: GNU Make [Substitution References](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs).

Comment: `PRJ_DEP += $(PRJ_OBJ:%.o=%.d)` should work too. The `%` doesn't differentiate between filename and extension. See also https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html

Comment: both of these suggestions will substitute more than just .c.o and .s.o files, which is likely not OP's intent.

Comment: `PRJ_DEP = $(patsubst %.c.o,%.c.d,$(patsubst %.s.o,%.s.d,$(PRJ_OBJ))`

Comment: @Danijel -- are you concerned about files such as `foo.o` (where it doesn't match the `.c.o` or `.s.o` pattern?   In which case, what would you want to occur for those files?   Note that your current solution would include `foo.o` in `PRJ_DEP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to only get `.d` files for `.c.o` and `.s.o` files, then you would have to do something like this:

```
PRJ_DEP = $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$(filter %.c.o %.s.o,$(PRJ_OBJ)))
```

The `$(filter ...` would get rid of any files you don't want to create corresponding `.d` files for and then you simply replace the `.o` with a `.d` using `$(patsubst...`

If, on the otherhand you know that `PRJ_OBJ` only contains `.c.o` and `.s.o` files, then you can go with @Vroomfondel or @urcodebetterznow's suggestions and simply do:

```
PRJ_DEP += $(PRJ_OBJ:%.o=%.d)
```

Comment: `PRJ_DEP += $(PRJ_OBJ:%.o=%.d)` works just fine.